# How to make(convert) a sidebar made with HTML,CSS and JS to one with only HTML and CSS. (They should be identical)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a big (or small depending on your level :) problem hat I hope someone can help me with. I have two different menus.

The first menu is made with HTML, CSS, JS (jQuery).

The idea of the second menu is that it should resemble the first one but it should only be done with HTML and CSS (So NO JavaScript).

I have tried myself but can’t seem to find the solution, I am providing the link to them both menus.

If anything is unclear, Please write to me.

Thanks :)

In CodePen

[With HTML,CSS and JS](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VaZrrY#0)

[Without JS (Only HTML and CSS)](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LNPepN)

**With HTML, CSS and JS**

```js
// close small meny   
$("#sidebar-close").click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $("#sidebar-wrapper").toggleClass("active");
    });

    // open small meny
    $("#sidebarr").click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $("#sidebar-wrapper").toggleClass("active");
    });

    // scrolling feature
    $(function() {
      $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
        if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') || location.hostname == this.hostname) {

          var target = $(this.hash);
          target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
          if (target.length) {
            $('html,body').animate({
              scrollTop: target.offset().top
            }, 1000);
            return false;
          }
        }
      });
    });
```

```css
#sidebar-wrapper {
  z-index: 1000;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  width: 250px;
  height: 50%;
  margin-right: -250px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background: #1dc491;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
  -o-transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
  transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
}
.sidebar-nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 250px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
.sidebar-nav li {
  text-indent: 20px;
  line-height: 40px;
}
.sidebar-nav li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 700
}
.sidebar-nav li a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
}
.sidebar-nav li a:active,
.sidebar-nav li a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-menu {
  height: 55px;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 55px;
}
.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-menu a {
  color: #fff;
}
.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-menu a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background: none;
}
#sidebarr {
  z-index: 1;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
#sidebar-wrapper.active {
  right: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
  -o-transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
  transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
}
.space {
  margin: 5px 5px 0 0;
}
.btn-green {
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #1dc491;
}


.btn-green:hover,
.btn-green:focus,
.btn-green:active {
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}
.btn-white {
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #333;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  float: right;
}
.btn-white:hover,
.btn-white:focus,
.btn-white:active {
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #333;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
}
```

```html
    <div id="sidebarr" class="btn btn-green btn-lg space"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></div>
    <nav id="sidebar-wrapper">
        <ul class="sidebar-nav">
            <a id="sidebar-close" class="btn btn-white btn-lg space"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
            <li class="sidebar-menu">
                <a href="#index">Hem</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#omoss">Om oss</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#section-4">Kontakt</a>
            </li>
           
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

Without JS (Only HTML and CSS)

```css
.btn-green {
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #1dc491;
    padding: 20px
}

.btn-green:hover,
.btn-green:focus,
.btn-green:active {
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
}

.btn-white {
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: #333;
    background-color: rgb(255,255,255);
    float: right;
}

.btn-white:hover,
.btn-white:focus,
.btn-white:active {
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: #333;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
}


/* Meny */
.btn-green {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.btn-green:focus .onclick-menu-content {
    /*  opacity is 1 in opened state (see below) */
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;

    /* don't let pointer-events affect descendant elements */
    pointer-events: auto;
}
.onclick-menu-content {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;

    /* use opacity to fake immediate toggle */
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    transition: visibility 0.5s;
}

.sidebar-nav {
    position: absolute;
    height: 500px;
    top: 0;
    width: 250px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;

  margin-left: -220px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.sidebar-nav li {
    text-indent: 20px;
    line-height: 40px;
}

.sidebar-nav li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 700
}

#sidebarr {
    z-index: 2;
    position:fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

```html
   <div id="sidebarr" tabindex="0" class="btn-green">
   <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
   <nav id="sidebar-wrapper">
    <ul class="onclick-menu-content sidebar-nav">
      <a id="sidebar-close" class="btn btn-white"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
       
        <li class="sidebar-menu">
                
                <li><a href="#index">Hem</a></li>
                <li><a href="#omoss">Om oss</a></li>
                <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
                <li><a href="#section-4">Kontakt</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

     </nav>
```

Comment: You're not going to be able to replicate the `click` functionality in your jquery just using only CSS and HTML.  What you're trying to do is not possible.

Comment: You actually can simulate click events using pseudo classes. Looks like in his codepen he's using :focus, which might work out ok in this scenario. I'm confused about the question overall, though. The CSS is totally different between the two, so that's obviously why they're not identical.